# Connecting to PostgreSQL in wsgi file

Tags: postgresql, apache2, psycopg2, wsgi

I ran into a 500 server error when trying to connect to PostgreSQL from wsgi file using psycopg2.

```
import psycopg2

def application(environ, start_response):

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("database = testdb, user = postgres, password = secret")
execept:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"

status = '200 OK'
output = 'Hello Udacity, Robert!'

response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)

return [output]
```

Comment: I think, the error message is missing in your question.

Comment: Yes, the server error log is:

10.0.2.2 - - [21/Oct/2018:03:05:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 801 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Oct/2018:03:05:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 801 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem. Looks like somehow my psycopg2 does not work so I got to reinstall it

Answer (score 1):

After the creation of a database ('udacity' in my case), a table ('hello' in my case) and the population ('Hello world' in my case):

```
# psql environment
CREATE DATABASE udacity;
CREATE TABLE hello(
word text);
INSERT INTO hello VALUES ('Hello world');
```

You have to install python dependencies:

```
# shell environment
sudo apt install python-psycopg2 libpq-dev
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install psycopg2
```

Then, the next *myapp.wsgi* script works for me:

```
import psycopg2

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Original message'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'), ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    # DB connection
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='udacity' user='ubuntu' host='localhost' password='udacity'")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * from hello""")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            output = row[0]
    except:
        output = 'E: Python script'
    return [output]
```